# Getting a URL of a record from HP TRIM's Desktop Client

Tags: hp-trim

Is it possible to copy the URL of a Record/Document from HP's TRIM and sent it to someone in order to download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of going about doing something like this. Assuming you're sending the link to someone on the same WAN, or the security-risky option of having your TRIM system internet accessible, what I'd do is build a simple web service over the top of the TRIM SDK. The TRIM SDK is COM (with a PIA wrapper) or a proper .Net assembly (in version 7.*), so a simple ASP.Net service would be quite easy.

Below is the code for an ASP.Net service I built, based on a code sample provided by HP (based on the TRIMSDKPIA20.dll, not the TRIM 7.0 HP.HPTRIM.SDK assembly). You could use it as a basis to make something more RESTful, but as it is, you'd call it using a URL like:
http://server/ViewRecord/recno=D11-001

You could then create an "External Link", an Addin based again on the SDK that you can register as a Right-Click option in the TRIM interface. Something like "Send Download URL..." that fires up an email and generates the URL, but that's a bit more complicated.

Anyway, the code for the webservice:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using TRIMSDK;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string errormsg = string.Empty;

        //Response.Clear();
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Database trim = new Database();
        trim.SetAsWebService();
        trim.Id = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["dbid"];
        trim.WorkgroupServerName = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["wgserver"];
        trim.WorkgroupServerPort = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["wgport"]);
        trim.Connect();
        string recno = Request.QueryString["recno"];
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(recno))
        {
            errormsg = "No recno parameter was passed.";
        }
        else
        {
            Record rec = trim.GetRecord(recno);
            if (rec == null)
            {
                errormsg = string.Format("Could not find a record with number \"{0}\". Either it doesn't exist, or you don't have permission to view it.", recno);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!rec.IsElectronic)
                {
                    errormsg = string.Format("Record {0} does not have an electronic attachment", rec.Number);
                }
                else
                {
                    IStream s = rec.GetDocumentStream(null, false, null);

                    Response.ClearHeaders();
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + rec.SuggestedFileName);
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", rec.DocumentSize.ToString());
                    Response.Buffer = false;
                    Response.ContentType = GetContentType(rec.Extension);

                    uint BufferSize = 10000;
                    uint DocumentLength = (uint)rec.DocumentSize;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
                    uint bytesread;
                    uint totalread = 0;

                    Stream outstream = Response.OutputStream;

                    while (totalread < DocumentLength)
                    {
                        s.RemoteRead(out buffer[0], 10000, out bytesread);
                        if (bytesread < 10000)
                        {
                            for (uint i = 0; i < bytesread; i++)
                            {
                                outstream.WriteByte(buffer[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            outstream.Write(buffer, 0, 10000);
                        }
                        totalread += bytesread;
                    }
                    outstream.Close();
                    Response.Flush();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        Response.Write(errormsg);
    }

    private string GetContentType(string fileExtension)
    {
        string ct = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\." + fileExtension.ToLower(), "Content Type", string.Empty) as string;

        if (ct.Length == 0)
        {
            ct = "application/octet-stream";
        }

        return ct;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Before TRIM 7, whether you can do this natively depends on which TRIM features are installed.
To see if you have the right stuff, make a TR5 file on your desktop, and rightclick on it - "TryURL" - copy the URL
(the TryURL right click action requires TRIM client stuff - if you don't have that, try opening the TR5 file in notepad, and see if there is a hyperlink in there).

You do get this functionality with the SharePoint connector for TRIM (TIPS or TSCI)

Or there is a cheap third party product that looks cool - from Icognition Pty Ltd.